# What did Gregory House see when he electrocuted himself?

Tags: house

In "97 seconds", episode 3 of season 4 of *House M.D.*, House electrocutes himself by putting a knife in socket. But when Wilson asks him what he saw, he does not reply. He wanted to talk to the guy who motivated him for the move, and in the end he told the main dead patient that "I'm sorry, I told you so."

It implies he had no afterlife experience, like the guy who electrocuted himself in the clinic, right?

Answer (score 3):

You answered your own question. House's stating "I told you so" implies that he didn't see anything (ie there is no afterlife).

http://house.wikia.com/wiki/97_Seconds

Comment: Of course, House probably isnt going to see the Light. Unless its red.